# Bash missing from the Dockerfile image

Tags: linux, bash, docker, shell, gitlab

I have the following Dockerfile:

```bash
#FROM zulu:8-jre-alpine
FROM azul/zulu-openjdk-alpine:8-jre

RUN sed -i 's/https/http/' /etc/apk/repositories 
#use this because of an issue with apk not working behind proxy on alpine3.13

# installing jq and envsubst binary, very usefull for shell templating
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache ca-certificates java-cacerts jq bash libintl tini \
    && apk --no-cache add -t p gettext \
    && cp /usr/bin/envsubst /usr/local/bin/envsubst \
    && apk del p

# Kaniko kontext use in build is /builds/infra/baseimages
# and kaniko/ssl/certs/ should be relateive path to the context
# Absolute path does not seem to be supported at kaniko 1.9.1 for COPY below
COPY ../../../kaniko/ssl/certs/ /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
RUN update-ca-certificates

# Zulu requires an additional symlink. Unlike OpenJDK the Zulu cacerts does not automatically symlink to /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
RUN rm $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts && ln -s /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts

RUN echo "export http_proxy=${HTTP_PROXY}" >> /etc/profile.d/proxy.sh && echo "export https_proxy=${HTTPS_PROXY}" >> /etc/profile.d/proxy.sh && echo "export no_proxy=${NO_PROXY}" >> /etc/profile.d/proxy.sh

COPY files/run-java.sh /usr/local/bin/
```

I install bash and I expect it to be there when I execute in the container but it is not.

Running `docker run -it --rm --entrypoint /bin/sh image`:

```bash
/ # bash
/bin/sh: bash: not found
/ # apk list bash
bash-5.1.16-r0 x86_64 {bash} (GPL-3.0-or-later) [installed]
```

It can see in the list also if I run `apk info bash`:

```bash
/ # apk info bash
bash-5.1.16-r0 description:
The GNU Bourne Again shell

bash-5.1.16-r0 webpage:
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/bash.html

bash-5.1.16-r0 installed size:
1296 KiB

/ #
```

If I do `apk del bash` and then `apk add bash` it sees it and it works.

```bash
/ # apk add bash
OK: 126 MiB in 45 packages
/ # bash
/bin/sh: bash: not found
/ # apk del bash
(1/4) Purging bash (5.1.16-r0)
Executing bash-5.1.16-r0.pre-deinstall
(2/4) Purging readline (8.1.1-r0)
(3/4) Purging ncurses-libs (6.3_p20211120-r1)
(4/4) Purging ncurses-terminfo-base (6.3_p20211120-r1)
Executing busybox-1.34.1-r7.trigger
OK: 123 MiB in 41 packages
/ # apk add bash
(1/4) Installing ncurses-terminfo-base (6.3_p20211120-r1)
(2/4) Installing ncurses-libs (6.3_p20211120-r1)
(3/4) Installing readline (8.1.1-r0)
(4/4) Installing bash (5.1.16-r0)
Executing bash-5.1.16-r0.post-install
Executing busybox-1.34.1-r7.trigger
OK: 126 MiB in 45 packages
/ # bash
```

We are using this Dockerfile as the base and then from this image it uses to build others like the one above:

```bash
#FROM kaniko:1.9.1
FROM gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:v1.9.1-debug AS kaniko

FROM alpine:3.15

# Use this because of an issue with apk not working behind proxy on alpine3.13/3.14
RUN sed -i 's/https/http/' /etc/apk/repositories

# Adding CAs so that my curl trusts internal resources AND apk trusts https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org behind our proxy
RUN echo "export http_proxy=${HTTP_PROXY}" >> /etc/profile.d/proxy.sh && echo "export https_proxy=${HTTPS_PROXY}" >> /etc/profile.d/proxy.sh && echo "export no_proxy=${NO_PROXY}" >> /etc/profile.d/proxy.sh

# Install necessary packages
RUN apk update \
    && apk --no-cache add \
       jq \
       yq \
       git \
       gettext \
       tzdata \
       unzip \
       bash \
       ca-certificates \
       openssl \
       coreutils

COPY --from=kaniko /kaniko/executor /kaniko/executor
COPY --from=kaniko /kaniko/docker-credential-gcr /kaniko/docker-credential-gcr
COPY --from=kaniko /kaniko/docker-credential-acr-env /kaniko/docker-credential-acr-env
COPY --from=kaniko /kaniko/.docker /kaniko/.docker
COPY --from=kaniko /kaniko/ssl/certs/ /kaniko/ssl/certs/
COPY --from=kaniko /etc/nsswitch.conf /etc/nsswitch.conf

COPY certs/* /kaniko/ssl/certs/

ENV SSL_CERT_DIR=/kaniko/ssl/certs/
ENV DOCKER_CONFIG /kaniko/.docker/
ENV DOCKER_CREDENTIAL_GCR_CONFIG /kaniko/.config/gcloud/docker_credential_gcr_config.json

ENTRYPOINT ["/kaniko/executor"]
```

I am guessing there is something happening that corrupts or makes bash not available in the first image but I am not sure exactly what or why it's happening for this one.

To give a bit more context:

- I am using Kaniko as the de facto executor but since we have multiple other images and scripts we need to install some additional packages to accommodate all the other builds of the images for our internal CR.
- What I noticed is that if I switch the base image from alpine3.15 to alpine3.12 all the other images that use or have alpine3.12 or alpine3.15 fail. In this case, since we use alpine3.15 4 images are failing from 45, which are the images that are using the same base image which is alpine3.15
- I can switch to using `ubuntu` or `debian-slim` but this still does not make me understand why by using the same image as `alpine3.15` for 2 different Dockerfiles will make packages unavailable or get corrupted from the first build.

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```bash
#FROM zulu:8-jre-alpine
FROM azul/zulu-openjdk-alpine:8-jre

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache ca-certificates java-cacerts jq bash libintl tini \
    && apk --no-cache add -t p gettext \
    && cp /usr/bin/envsubst /usr/local/bin/envsubst \
    && apk del p
```

Kaniko Dockerfile:

```bash
#FROM kaniko:1.9.1
FROM gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:v1.9.1-debug AS kaniko

FROM alpine:3.15

# Install necessary packages
RUN apk update \
    && apk --no-cache add \
       jq \
       yq \
       git \
       gettext \
       tzdata \
       unzip \
       bash \
       ca-certificates \
       openssl \
       coreutils

COPY --from=kaniko /kaniko/executor /kaniko/executor
COPY --from=kaniko /kaniko/docker-credential-gcr /kaniko/docker-credential-gcr
COPY --from=kaniko /kaniko/docker-credential-acr-env /kaniko/docker-credential-acr-env
COPY --from=kaniko /kaniko/.docker /kaniko/.docker
COPY --from=kaniko /kaniko/ssl/certs/ /kaniko/ssl/certs/
COPY --from=kaniko /etc/nsswitch.conf /etc/nsswitch.conf

ENV SSL_CERT_DIR=/kaniko/ssl/certs/
ENV DOCKER_CONFIG /kaniko/.docker/
ENV DOCKER_CREDENTIAL_GCR_CONFIG /kaniko/.config/gcloud/docker_credential_gcr_config.json

ENTRYPOINT ["/kaniko/executor"]
```

Comment: Alpine images don't normally include bash, but the `/bin/sh` that's included as part of the BusyBox base should be fine for almost all purposes.  Do you actually need bash here?  (Regardless of shell, a Docker container won't usually see files in `/etc/profile.d/`.)

Comment: Yes, that's why we added these extra packages. We need bash since we do some scripts that are written with bash syntax in mind instead of `/bin/sh` one. Yes, we can rewrite them to be `/bin/sh` but it would be a lot of work and break compatibility with some other images we are building that use natively `bash`.

Comment: Also it happens to fail only for these packages because if you see the `Dockerfile` for `kaniko` it has `alpine3.15` and there are 3-4 images that we are trying to build that underlying like this zulu one use `alpine3.15`. 

From my understanding it should just work because we even specify to add `bash` package but for some reason it gets corrupted or something happens to the image that it conflicts in a certain way that I am not exactly sure.

Comment: Can you reduce this to a [mcve] without things like the proxy, kaniko, and unrelated packages? Also include your build and run commands.

Comment: @BMitch done, see my latest edit in main post

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your error from the provided Dockerfile. I ran `docker build -t test-76091162 .` and `docker run -it --rm --entrypoint /bin/bash test-76091162` to get a working bash prompt.

Comment: Did you use the kaniko Dockerfile as the base and then from that tried to build on top of it the second Dockerfile?